# Rails, using collection model to update multiple records at once on a single form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to update multiple records on a single form in rails.

I've looked at [railscast #165](http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple-revised?autoplay=true/), but I'm trying to do it in a cleaner way.

Is there a way to create another model, a sort of collection model, and use accepts_nested_attributes for to update multiple records at once?

For example, there would be a normal ProductModel, and then a ProductCollections model.  The ProductCollections model would have_many products, and it would also accept_nested_attributes_for products.

I'm running into an issue since I'm trying to do this without creating a table for the ProductCollections model in the DB.  I'm also wondering how routing should work.

Comment: `Product.update()` will take a couple arrays of ids and attributes.  So, you can set up a PATCH method to take in many products and edit multiple at once.  Or you can do as you say and create a product_collection.  Is there any other object that is naturally a product_collection, like a 'store' or 'department' or something?

Comment: Yes, there is already a parent (store).  I'm not sure why I didn't think of that earlier.  I can just create a ProductCollectionController with it's own nested forms... but still just using the normal products model.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: You'd actually edit (and update) the store object in that case.  accepts_nested_attributes_for products would go on the store and you would then just submit to the update action.  That would all be on the stores_controller.

Comment: I agree it could stay on the store controller, but I figured it may be better to use a separate controller since they're separate forms are they will redirect to different paths after the update.

Comment: If you are conceptually updating a store, then I'd put it on the stores controller - add a new PUT action to handle it (eg 'update_store_products').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Sward's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/177489/swards) comment, a new model wasn't needed.  Since each product already has a parent (store), I can use the `Store` model with `accepts_nested_attributes_for :products`.

I just created a separate collections controller for products (to handle the incoming form submission and redirect) and a view with a form with `fields_for` to update multiple records at once.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way:
(following the example from railscast, with a newer version of Rails)

```
Product.where(id: params[:product_ids]).update_all(discontinued: true)
```

It is more readable than the previous version of the API. You select the products first with the typical search API and then apply the update_all to the result of that query.

The ProductCollection is the result of a given query with the ProductModel class. It does not need a database table of its own.

Comment: I wanted to keep my question somewhat simple, but in reality, my products have another model nested under them.  Would it be possible to update those as well using your method?  I was thinking about that accepts_nested_attributes_for way since it's easy to do multiple levels of nesting.

Comment: I believe you could do that. In those params should be nested values. For example if accepts nested attributes for :item, then within the change params, you should have item_attributes: {updated_at: Time.now}